# 3D AR Drawing app lagging and frame speed drops significantly while drawing

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, arkit

I am new to ARKit. I am trying to add so many new nodes into the sceneview in front of my camera. I wanna add objects like cylinder and sphere with different colors. the problem is my frame speed will drop significantly and my phone starts to lag so much after I add 30 objects to the scene. I searched for a solution so much and I found this function to be helpful. [prepare(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523375-prepare). This was how I was adding my objects to the scene without prepare function.

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cylinder)
```

and now I am using the prepare function like this:

```
self.sceneView.prepare([cylinder], completionHandler: { (success) in 
     self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cylinder)
})
```

Now frame drops like before, also the app will crash after adding 50 objects to the scene.

I think I am not using it correctly and I don't know how to use it?!

Also, I am thinking what else I can do to better my ARKit app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you're adding the objects is independent of the frame rate that you're seeing, and when you use all the memory available. The different method of adding objects can be useful for keeping the UI responsive, but you will need to optimize (or use more powerful hardware) when placing a lot of objects into an ARKit scene.

If you're trying to understand your ARKit performance, the [medium article on ARKit 1.5 vs. 2.0](https://medium.com/@valv0/wwdc18-arkit2-vs-arkit1-5-2d-tracking-performances-comparison-59aec7be7d20) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know that I have to somehow optimize my app. Does it help if I use Metal? @heckj

Comment: @Bank scenekit will automatically use Metal, so while that's a good thought, the path you started on is (likely) already leveraging it. I found a couple of articles that talk to optimizing, but go light on details:
- <https://medium.com/@abhinavpraksh/good-practices-for-better-ar-experience-arkit-75e200af7581>
- <https://medium.com/coletiv-stories/augmented-reality-6c7be8ab7fde>

The core will likely be optimizing OpenGL objects, textures, and just trying to wring the max you can CPU/GPU out of whatever system you have.